# Targeting Tbody while inserting data into a table using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am using the code below to insert data into a table :

```
function addRow() {
    var key = $('#save_key').val();
    var qry = query();
    var table = document.getElementById("qrytbl");
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    row.insertCell(-1).innerHTML = qry;
    row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = key;
}
```

> My Table Structure

```
<table id=qrytbl>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Key</th>
                            <th>Query</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

The code inserts data inside the `<thead>` tag instead of `<tbody>` which is where I want it t be. How can I specify `<tbody>` path within my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#qrytbl tobdy").append("put data here");
```

Also you have an error in your code: Wrap the Id in " " like this:

```
<table id="qrytbl">
```

Yes this will insert into the right row providing you enter the correct mark up:

here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tt88g8of/

```
<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell 1</td>
            <td>Cell 2</td>
        </tr>           
    </thead>        
    <tbody>        
    <tbody>       

</table>

<div class="clk">insert row</div>


$(".clk").on("click", function(){

    var data = "<tr> <td>CEll 1 data </td> <td>cell 2 data</td></tr>";

    $("#example tbody").append(data);
});
```